# Measurable set in $[0,1]$ with relatively large intersection with all intervals

Tags: measure-theory

The question is whether or not there exists a Lebsgue measurable set $E\subset [0,1]$ with $m(E)=.9$ and for all intervals $I\subset [0,1]$ $m(E\cap I)>.1\,m(I)$. I believe that I have seen a similar question to this before and the answer was yes, but the construction was very involved and you had to do some business with creating lots of fat cantor sets in intervals with rational end-points.

If $q_1,q_2,...$ is an enumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$ and $I_{n,m}=(\min\{q_n,q_m\},\max\{q_n,q_m\})$, then we can construct a fat cantor set of measure $.9$ in $I_{n,m}$ by successively removing the middle $1/10^{\text{th}}$ of intervals in $I_{n,m}$ and then taking intersections, same as with the usual cantor set. Say that $C_{n,m}$ is the resulting fat cantor set. Now my only guess for what $E$ could possibly be is $\bigcap_{n,m}C_{n,m}$, but I have no idea how to show that it has measure $.9$, much less that it has the other desired property with intervals in $[0,1]$.

If I am going down the wrong track let me know.

Comment: There is no such measurable $E$. To prove it, apply the Lebesgue density theorem to the complement of $E$.